# cmake 2.8.9 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, apt, cmake

I have installed `cmake` using `apt-get` and the "latest" version is 2.8.0.

But when I try to used, my project requires `cmake` version 2.8.9.

I try to update but without any success using `apt-get`.

How can I get `cmake` 2.8.9 on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: cmake 2.8.9 is available in the official repos for Ubuntu 12.10. You should consider upgrade your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile `cmake` yourself or can can update your Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (to [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all) and then) to [Ubuntu 12.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all), which is the recommended method because the support for 10.04 (desktop) ends in April 2013.

Comment: Actualy cmake version in Ubuntu 12.04 is 2.8.7, he should upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @EricCarvalho [yes, you are right](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cmake&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all).

Answer (score 8):

open your terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and then type as

```
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386.sh
chmod +x cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386.sh
./cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386.sh
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when I have the folder with cmake what I have to do? This script doesn't install cmake...Thanks

Comment: give me ls of that

Comment: user@user-NC10:~/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386$ ls                            
**bin  cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386.sh  doc  man  share**                 thanks for the help!

Comment: and the installation log please

Comment: By default the CMake will be installed in:
  "/home/giacomo/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386"
Do you want to include the subdirectory cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386?
Saying no will install in: "/home/giacomo/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386" [Yn]: 
Y

Using target directory: /home/giacomo/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386/cmake-2.8.10.2-Linux-i386
Extracting, please wait...

Unpacking finished successfully

Comment: This downloads `cmake` but doesn't install it. You can't just overwrite the binaries in `/usr/bin` with these, either.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu/Debian way for building from source :

```
sudo aptitude install devscripts
dget -x -u http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3.dsc
sudo aptitude build-dep cmake
cd cmake* && fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -d
sudo dpkg -i ../cmake*deb
```

This will create a local backport and install it. Substitute almost any other package that has a newer DSC available.

Comment: `cmake_2.8.9-0ubuntu1.dsc:
dscverify: cmake_2.8.9-0ubuntu1.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: Signature made Thu 16 Aug 2012 11:52:34 AM CEST using DSA key ID DD4D5088
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Validation FAILED!!` How to solve this? I thought it was a Ubuntu package?

Comment: Solution to that error: add `-u ` to dget command.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.10.tar.gz
tar xzvf cmake-2.8.10.tar.gz
cd cmake-2.8.10
./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 12.04.
I had to close and reopen my terminal to see the version change.

```
cmake --version
```

cmake version 2.8.10

Comment: what you said works, I got `2.8.10` on `cmake --version`. However, when I try to use the Cmake I get `CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /CMakeSystem.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:172 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
`

Comment: it is some linux permission problem ... I have to do `sudo cmake ..` and `sudo make` to make it work ...
Do you know how to set the rights properly to be able to use `cmake` without `sudo` ?